# Cypher syntax error with neo4h python driver

Tags: python, neo4j

I'm trying to parse a CSV with strings of AD groups into Neo4j. I'm using the python driver and following the quick example.

```
import csv
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase

driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost:7687", auth=("neo4j", "neo"))

def print_friends(tx, name):
    for record in tx.run("MATCH (a:User) WHERE a.name = $name "
                         "RETURN a.name ORDER BY a.name", name=name):
        print(record["a.name"])

def create_group(tx, name):
    print "create group: " + name
    tx.run("MERGE (g:Group {name: $name}) ", {"name": name})

def set_group_label(tx, name, label):
    label = ":" + label
    print "set label: " + name +" "+ label
    tx.run("MATCH (g:Group) "
           "WHERE g.name = $name "
           "SET g $label", name=name, label=label)

with open('../transfer/ALLADUsersGroups_201704180501.csv', 'rb') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(x.replace('\0', '') for x in file)
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        if i==102435:
            with driver.session() as session:
                session.write_transaction(create_group, row[1].split("=")[1])
                session.write_transaction(set_group_label, row[1].split("=")[1], row[1].split("=")[0])
```

I'm trying to set a new label based on the type of the group, eg. {CN, OU, DC, etc.}.
However I'm getting the following error:

```
neo4j.exceptions.CypherSyntaxError: Unexpected end of input: expected an identifier character, whitespace or a relationship pattern (line 1, column 50 (offset: 49))
"MATCH (g:Group) WHERE g.name = $name SET g $label"
                                                  ^
```

Am I doing something wrong is this something wrong with the driver?

I should say I've followed the installation instructions from here: [Neo4j Driver for Python](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-python-driver/tree/20cbad87187b219d8ff208ae5df47cf64df1d939)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for setting a label uses `:` like so: `SET g:Thing`. However, I don't believe Cypher allows setting of dynamic labels like this.

You'll likely need to use string concatenation for this particular case, appending the label string in the appropriate place in the query, or by using [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_creating_data) to dynamically add the label from a string.